# DAPM routing in ALSA

Tags: linux, alsa

I need some clarification on ALSA Layer. My Audio codec driver has DAPM widgets and DAPM routes. This is used while registering Codec. 
Similarly machine driver has a different set of DAPM widgets and DAPM routes. This is used while registering Card.

Can someone tell me whether Audio codec driver and Machine driver DAPM widgets and routes need to be same ?

Thanks
MP

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer...

DAPM routing can be placed either in DT (machine driver will use) or Codec driver. It need not be configured in both Codec driver and Machine driver.